# SSLError: Not a directory

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests

I am using the excellent `requests` module in an embedded version of Python 2.7  in a C++ application on Mac OS. My code runs fine on my Mac, but it doesn't on a client's machine. He is using the same version of Python and the C++ host application. The error he gets with the following URL is:

```
http://www.hantmade.com/backstage/thumb/1450544739_Impression%20XL%20300%20RZ.stage.png

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "'hantmade-storage.pyp'", line 1468, in online_load_thumbnail
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\api.py", line 69, in get
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\api.py", line 50, in request
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\sessions.py", line 597, in send
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\sessions.py", line 195, in resolve_redirects
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
  File "c:\maxon\cinema 4d r16 dev\plugins\hantmade_storage\devel\requests/requests\adapters.py", line 433, in send
SSLError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
```

> Note: The absolute Windows-style paths seem to stem from the fact that the `requests` module is loaded from a set of `.pyc` files and *apparently* the original source file's path is compiled into them.

Once again, I can not reproduce this issue on my Mac unfortunately. Where could this error come from? Why "not a directory"? Are there any steps to debugging this problem?

If necessary, I can log into the client's machine via TeamViewer and modify the source code to debug the problem, only I didn't feel the need for it yet since I am completely puzzled by this error.

**Update 2016-03-15**

Suddenly the I also get an SSLError and the message on the side of my client has changed also. Strangely, nothing really changed in the code. I'll keep on googling, these error messages appear to be informative and eventually there are already discussions about them.

What my client sees:

```
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:326: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

What I see:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "Not a directory" error, we figured that the distributed version of the software did not pack the request module's `cacert.pem` file into the Python Egg. That was one issue.

The other issue seems to be that when using Python 2.6 or older, the `ssl` module failed to communicate with the server. I was able to solve this by compiling the Python [SSL module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl/) manually in a newer version. Since the software runs in an embedded version of Python, I can't just go bonkers with the dependencies and make my software as encapsulated as possible. I use my [`_localimport`](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/localimport) class to temporarily remove the original `ssl` module, import the new compiled `ssl` module and `requests`.

```
with _localimport(lib_path) as importer:
  importer.disable(['ssl', 'requests'])
  import ssl, requests
  assert issubpath(ssl.__file__, lib_path)
  assert issubpath(requests.__file__, lib_path)
```

Libs Folder:

```
libs/
  ssl-1.16-macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.6.egg
  requests-v2.9.1.egg
```

Note that these problems with SSL only ocurred on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same issue when installing my package (which depends on a local installation of the requests module) through setup tools. The pem file doesn't get packed along with the egg.